# Show canvas rectangle below imageView and textView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have

```
imageView 
TextView
Rectangle drawn from canvas
```

I am doing

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                drawView = new DrawView(this);
                drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                setContentView(drawView);
    setContentView(R.layout.description);// If this get invoked then how will `drawView` will get overlapped.
// then normal 


            }


            public class DrawView extends View {
                Paint paint = new Paint();

                public DrawView(Context context) {
                    super(context);            
                }

                @Override
                public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                     paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
                    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
                   paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
                    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );




                }
```

**Edit 1**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_new_oct23);

        episode_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_EpisodeImage);
        characters=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_Characters);
progressBarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.timerDisplay);
        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);
    progressBarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.timerDisplay);
        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);
        //  drawView = new DrawView(this);
        progressBarLayout.addView(drawView);






    }

    public class DrawView extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);            
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            /* paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
           paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );

             */
            draw(canvas);


        }


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void draw(Canvas canvas){

            int width = 0;  
            int height = 0;  
            Point size = new Point();
            WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)    {
                w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
                width = size.x;
                height=size.y;

            }else{
                Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
                width = d.getWidth(); 
                height=d.getHeight();
            }
            Random rnd = new Random(); 
            int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));  
            width=width-20;
            int margin=width/SIZE;
            int begin=10;

            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);    
            for (int iTmp=0;iTmp<SIZE;iTmp++){
                begin=begin+(iTmp)*(margin);
                //  begin=begin-2;
                System.out.println("onkar "+begin);

                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                canvas.drawRect(begin, 20, margin-2, 30, paint);

            }

        }

    }

        //  drawView = new DrawView(this);
        progressBarLayout.addView(drawView);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an approach like this:

```
// set content view
setContentView(R.layout.description);
// get the parent of imageview and textview, i'll suppose its LinearLayout.
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
// then add your view, since its a linear layout it will automatically be added below textview. for other layouts you use LayoutParams to position your View.
ll.addView(new DrawView());
```

Comment: progressBarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.timerDisplay);

  DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);

  drawView = new DrawView(this);

  progressBarLayout.addView(drawView);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FrameLayout to stack the views and use a SurfaceView as bottom view to draw on.